# ShapeableImageView doest show vector image

Tags: android, kotlin, vector, android-imageview

hi I have following code, it shows png but fails to show vector images:

```
  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_isurance_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_car_body"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/blue_round_outline"
    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```